# Ошибка при работе с PySerial

Tags: python, pyserial

Я установил PySerial

`pip install pyserial`

Когда я в проекте пишу

```
import serial
```

Ошибок нет, но когда я пишу

```
s = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baudrate=115200)
```

Происходит ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Project\Python\CameraMetr\serial.py", line 1, in <module>
import serial
File "E:\Project\Python\CameraMetr\serial.py", line 3, in <module>
arduino = serial.serial(port='COM3', baudrate=115200)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Вот весь код:

```
import serial
import time
s = serial.serial(port='COM3', baudrate=115200)
while True:
    print(s.readline())
```

Но при запуске такого кода:

```
import Serial
serial.Serial()
```

Выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Project\Python\CameraMetr\serial.py", line 1, in <module>
    import serial
  File "E:\Project\Python\CameraMetr\serial.py", line 2, in <module>
    serial.Serial()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial' (most likely due to a circular import). Did you mean: 'serial'?
```

Comment: import serial - надо, а потом serial.Serial(...)

Comment: может порт открыть надо. как это обычно делается перед передачей данных?   s.open()

Answer (score 1):

https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html#opening-serial-ports

Класс Serial с большой буквы пишется

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает

Comment: @Danil а ошибка какая получается когда Вы пишите serial.Serial('COM3', 115200) ?

Comment: Да, ошибка происходит когда я пишу serial.Serial('COM3', 115200)

Comment: Пробовал переустановить Python, не помогло

Comment: А ошибка TypeError: 'module' object is not callable ? Поправьте вопрос и ошибки там

Comment: У Вас хоть COM порты-то есть?

Comment: А название модуля пишется с маленькой!